# GStreamer Two Piplines Synchronization

Tags: gstreamer

I have developed an application which takes data from file and add metadata to each frame and transfer that data to client through udp over rtp.

At receiver end client removes that metadata and has to play the video.

for that I used At server End:

```
pipeline1 :: gst-launch-1.0 filesrc ! videoparse ! appsink
```

at appsink adding metadata and push that buffer to appsrc.

```
pipeline 2 :: gst-launch-1.0 appsrc ! rtpgstpay ! udpsink
```

At Receivers end ::

```
pipeline1 :: gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc ! rtpgstdepay ! appsink
```

at appsink removing the metadata and push the buffer to appsrc.

```
pipeline2 :: gst-launch-1.0 appsrc ! videoparse ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink
```

The Problem is At receivers end i am not getting all the frames and the video also not playing properly. Only one frame playing and stopping and again playing only single frame.

Can anyone provide some solution or suggestion?

/* code At Server End Processing Frame */

```
/* This is in Function which is called by g_timeout_add_seconds(0, new_sample, NULL);

g_signal_emit_by_name(sink, "pull-sample", &sample, NULL);
buf = gst_buffer_new_wrapped(&header, sizeof(header)); // header is Structure
FrameBuffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
buffer = gst_buffer_append(buf, FrameBuffer);

g_signal_emit_by_name (appsrc2, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);

        if(ret != GST_FLOW_OK)
        {
                g_printerr("Failed to Push Buffer");
                return FALSE;
        }
        g_print("Successfully Pushed..\n");

/* Above code is for processing frame at server end. */
```

/* Code For Processing Frame At Receiver END */

```
//This is in Function new_sample which is called by g_timeout_add_seconds(0, new_sample, NULL);
        if(!gst_app_sink_is_eos ((GstAppSink *)sink))
        {
            GstSample *sample = NULL;
            g_signal_emit_by_name(sink, "pull-sample", &sample, NULL); 
              buf = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
              gst_buffer_extract(buf, 0, temp, 8);
              if(frameid != temp->FrameID)
              {
                gst_element_set_state(pipeline2, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
              g_print("Frame Header :: %d , Frame ID :: %d\n", temp->FrameHeader, temp->FrameID);
            gint size;
            size = gst_buffer_get_size(buf);
            buffer = gst_buffer_copy_region(buf, GST_BUFFER_OFFSET_NONE, 8, size-8);
            g_print("Size :: -- %d\n",size);
            g_signal_emit_by_name (appsrc, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);
            if(ret != GST_FLOW_OK)
            {
                    g_printerr("Failed to Push Buffer");
                    return FALSE;
            }
            g_print("Successfully Pushed..\n");
```

Comment: what about setting is-live=TRUE on the appsrc? also check the signal enough-data on appsrc. It would be helpful if you provide details about  pipelines in gst-launch like format (element ! element2 ! etc ,,)

Comment: Pipeline One :: gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc ! queue ! rtpgstdepay ! appsink

at appsink i am modifying the buffer and the modified buffer is sent to appsrc by push-buffer signal.

Pipeline Two :: gst-launch-1.0 appsrc ! queue ! videoparse ! autovideoconvert ! autovideosink

Comment: please update the Question so that also other people will see it right away - thus better chance of somebody answering your question :)

Comment: can you add some code on how you process the frames?

Comment: What is the format of the video (are you sure with the videoparse, don't you need some demux there for example qtdemux for mp4)? when you join the pipeline1 and 2 on sender and pipe1 and 2 on receiver leaveing out the metadata processing is it working properly?

Comment: /* This is in Function which is called by g_timeout_add_seconds(0, new_sample, NULL);

g_signal_emit_by_name(sink, "pull-sample", &sample, NULL);
buf = gst_buffer_new_wrapped(&header, sizeof(header)); // header is Structure
FrameBuffer = gst_sample_get_buffer(sample);
buffer = gst_buffer_append(buf, FrameBuffer);

g_signal_emit_by_name (appsrc2, "push-buffer", buffer, &ret);

  if(ret != GST_FLOW_OK)
  {
    g_printerr("Failed to Push Buffer");
    return FALSE;
  }
  g_print("Successfully Pushed..\n");

/* Above code is for processing frame at server end. */

Comment: Format Of the video is YUV